# How to center page with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

On this [Website](http://djkarmamusic.com/) I am developing, I am having a problem centering the content on the first media query break.  The 768px size doesnt line up against the left side of the browser window and allow me to resize the window on down, something is holding it open.  The page centers normally on a 960px and larger browser size, but not the 768px.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a side note (you probably know it already) - when you put the website in production stage, consider further compressing your images. The entire website needs `4.44s` to load on 100Mbps connection - `3.78s` onload (most of which are images) and `2.03s` DOMContentLoad . `1.70MB` split into `61 different` requests is somehow too much - for example stack overflow has only `75.26KB` and  only takes `568ms` for DOMContentLoad. Sorry if this is obvious and you already know all that - it's just something that stroke me immediately as an end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `min-width: 980px` on your body fixed it for me.